# How to transfer mp4 from my pc to iTunes then from iTunes to my iPhone?

Tags: itunes, iphone, mp4

I've downloaded some youtube video, converted them to mp4 and I'd now like to transfer to my iphone through itune I can't find anything that explains this on internet. So is it possible (without buying some software)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag the file into the iTunes window or go to "File" -> "Add file to library". Then select the mp4 file.

Next, go to your iPhone's page by clicking it on the left. Now there should be a tab that says "Video". There, select to sync the video you added to iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple's official website, iPad/iTunes is only compatible with H.264, MPEG-4 or Motion JPEG video format with the following specifications:

- If it is H.264 video, it should meet: up to 720p, 30 frames per second, Main Profile level 3.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;
- If it is MPEG-4 video, it should meet: up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;
- If it is Motion JPEG (M-JPEG), it should meet: up to 35 Mbps, 1280 by 720 pixels, 30 frames per second, audio in ulaw, PCM stereo audio in .avi file format.

If the MP4 video is not in the above technical specification, you will fail to transfer MP4 to iTunes or fail to play MP4 on iPad or iPad2.

Comment: Could you link to the original page at Apple.com? BTW, does it all still applies for retina iPhones / iPads?